# Azure & VS Mac, SSL

Tags: .net, azure, mono, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-mac

I am currently migrating my **MVC .NET Core project** from **Windows Visual Studio 2017** to **Visual Studio for Mac**. I host my database on **Azure** and I get the following error.

```
SSL encryption for data sent between client and server is not implemented.
```

- I tried changing the Encrypt in the connectionString to false.
- Changed TrustServerCertificate to true
- Install the System.Data.SqlClient
- Restore packages and include it in the .csproj

This error exists in the Mono Project for years. People were saying that by the release of .NET Core and Visual Studio for Mac this problem will be resolve.However, it didn't.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is built upon Mono, not .NET Core, so the release of .NET Core and Visual Studio for Mac won't solve everything yet, and that's why Azure support in Visual Studio for Mac is still in Beta channel. Wait if you can, or switch back to Windows and Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't want to switch back to Windows. I'll probably wait

Comment: Azure support for Visual Studio Mac is available in the stable channel. With an ASP.NET Core project it will be running with .NET Core not Mono. So presumably the SSL error is from .NET Core. Did you try running it from the command line using `dotnet run` or `dotnet path/to/assembly.dll`? The error message does seem to be a Mono error - unless the SqlClient assembly is using similar error messages.

Comment: Should I change the built target? Because now the only one I have is the mono, no other options